# Bootstrap datepicker ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

I've been trying to render [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) using this macro created based on docs:

```
    {% macro render_datepicker(field) %} 
<div class='input-group date' id="{{ field.id }}">   
<input type="text" class="form-control" />   <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span> </div> 
<script type="text/javascript">   $(function () {
            $('{{ field.id }}').datetimepicker();   }) </script> 
{% endmacro %}
```

Static files serving JS in my Flask template:

```
<script src="//upcdn.b0.upaiyun.com/libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/plugins.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/vendor/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/vendor/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
```

Console prints:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (anonymous function)
```

Comment: sounds like jquery has not loaded when this code is run

Comment: So the question should be: is it possible to use javascript inside Jinja2 template? Maybe it's rendered before jquery is loaded in main template.

Comment: I would look at the html of the page to see the order of rendering of the different bits (I know nothing of Jinja2) but this does sound more like a timing/ordering issue in the browser